# $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

im getting a $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop, but i cant see what is wrong with my function.

controller:

```
vm.isAccount = function(account) {
            ActiveUserProfileService.isAccount(account).then(
                function (result) {
                    console.log("Result is");
                    console.log(result);
                    return result;

                }
            );
        };
```

View:

```
<ul ng-if="sidebarCtrl.isAccount('admin')">
...
</ul>
```

Comment: How do you know that the error is caused by this code? What does the entire error message say?

Comment: Never ever do such thing.. You're calling function on `ng-if` which has ajax request. You know, that is getting called on each digest cycle..which is triggering digest cycle more than 10 times TTL, and `$rootScope:infdig` error is getting thrown